# C++: What library to include when only wanting to use size_t?

Tags: c++, include, size-t

I am learning C++. One of the data members of my classes is supposed to be of type `size_t`. Now `size_t` is not a built-in primitive type but rather a defined type (as an unsigned value that usually is at least as large as an int) that is heavily used all around C++.

Many of the C++ libraries, such as `iostream` or `string` will automatically add `size_t` to your current scope.

However, my class does not need to include any fancy libraries. As I want to keep it as lean as possible, I only want to include the file responsible for creating `size_t`.

Which library is this?

Comment: [Pick one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). For your stated desire, i'd probably go with `<cstddef>`

Comment: I sometimes do this, when nobody is watching: `typedef decltype(sizeof(1)) size_t;`  It won't cause an error because `size_t` is supposed to be the type given by the `sizeof` operator, and type re-definitions only fail when the base type is different than a previous definition.  It may be more palatable if enclosed in your own namespace, though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `#include <cstddef>`

Also see here for details http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/

Answer (score 4):

`size_t` is defined by `<stddef.h>`, in both C++ and C.

In C++ you can alternatively include `<cstddef>`, and then write `std::size_t`. Plain `size_t` may compile or not, but is not guaranteed available with this header. However, I don't recommend this, since it has no advantage, and has the problem that if you forget the `std::`, or it's not there in other code that gets included, the code may fail to compile with some other compiler.

Due to the problems with implicit conversion to unsigned common type in expressions, consider using signed `ptrdiff_t` instead of `size_t`, with the exception of template parameters. The exception is because at least one much used compiler has problems matching a non-`size_t` template parameter with e.g. a raw array size.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but probably it is due to the fact that you suggest not to use `cstddef` and instead prefer `stddef.h` in C++. Mixing C and C++ code is not a matter of preferring a `std::`-less type actually.

Comment: @skypjack: Well maybe but that would be inane, as stated. Using `cstddef` has no advantages and it does have problems. It's there for historical reasons, and the support for original rationale was removed in C+11.

Comment: @skypjack: Regarding your strawman argument "Mixing C and C++ code is not a matter of preferring a std::-less type actually", one would have to be extraordinarily challenged in order to believe that in the first place. Where the *!"#& did you get the inspiration for that?

Comment: I even don't know what _strawman_ means!! That's one of the problems of non-native speakers. On the other side, _*!"#&_ is quite common. :-)